# Unable to transfer file to S3 bucket with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to transfer a png image to a S3 bucket that I have on AWS with Python and boto3, unfortunately I'm getting an error when I run my script in the command prompt.

Below is the Python script I'm using with boto3:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'myAccessKey'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'mySecurityKey'
BUCKET_NAME = 'myBucketName'

data = open('C:/Python27/Scripts/test.png','rb')

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='test.png', Body=data)

print ("Done")
```

Here is the error I'm getting when I run the script:

**Image of error**

[image: Image of error]

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like a version mismatch or dependency installation issue.

Comment: Is boto3 a Python2 library? I'd try the whole thing with python 3, python 2 is at end of life. Also open without close is not good, either use close or with.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting credentials into your source code, it is recommended that you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command, which will store the credentials in a configuration file.

You can then simply upload a file with code like this:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

s3.upload_file('C:/Python27/Scripts/test.png', 'my-bucket', 'test.png')
```

(Set the region as appropriate for your bucket.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Looks like the error is resolved. the PNG was transferred successfully.